# Logic Apps HTTP PUT to save to Blob Storage is saving as wrong Content-Type

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I am using a Logic App to save excel files from an Outlook inbox into a Blob Storage. This is the code I am using.

[image]

```
"HTTP": {
   "inputs": {
      "authentication": {
         "audience": "https://storage.azure.com",
         "type": "ManagedServiceIdentity"
      },
      "body": "@items('For_each')?['ContentBytes']",
      "headers": {
         "x-ms-blob-type": "BlockBlob",
         "x-ms-version": "2019-07-07"
      },
      "method": "PUT",
      "uri": "blob storage path"
   },                            
   "type": "Http"
}
```

My issue is that the file is being saved as Content-Type "application/octet-stream", instead of "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet". Is there a way I can change the Content-Type?

Comment: Can you show your flow in a screenshot?  From what I can work out, you're using the HTTP action, is that right?

Comment: yea im using HTTP action. see edits

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the HTTP end point then you should be able to specify the content type in the header, as per the documentation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob

[image: Content-Type]

If that doesn’t work, try the other one listed which actually looks like the right one to use ... **x-ms-blob-content-type**

[image: HTTP]

Comment: I added this but it is still saving as application/octet-stream. I checked the run history and the attachment inputted has the correct ContentType. Not sure why it's still saving as application/octet-stream

Comment: Just updated my answer. Something I overlooked. That’s gotta be it, surely.

Comment: thanks that worked, but when I open the file I get another error saying the file is corrupt

Comment: It answered your question though didn't it?  :-)  Question, why do you need to store it as a specific content-type?  We've stored txt, json, excel, all sorts of files and even though they go up as octet-stream, they always come out fine once you download and open them so maybe just leave it as is?

Comment: Did you receive your issue.. I'm also in same situation but I'm getting an error like:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>ContainerNotFound</Code><Message>The specified container does not exist.
RequestId:9b0e354d-a01e-0027-18bc-b3bb87000000
Time:2023-07-11T05:55:21.6723692Z</Message></Error>

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement, you can use `Create blob (V2)` to directly save the outlook's excel file attachment to blob storage.

[image]

Comment: i was originally using create blob and it was working fine, but we had to switch to http cause of some security thing was blocking access. so i have to use http now